# Android: Erro ao utilizar Retrofit com conversor XML

Tags: android, retrofit

Estou a fazer um exemplo simples de Retrofit em Android com um conversor XML, mas cada vez que executo obtenho a seguinte excepção:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.simpleframework.xml.core.ValueRequiredException: Unable to satisfy @org.simpleframework.xml.Element(data=false, name=title, required=true, type=void) on field 'title' private java.lang.String com.rdev.testes.Channel.title for class com.rdev.testes.Channel at line 2
```

O formato do meu XML é:

```
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
 <title>Testes</title>
 <description>Primeira Descrição</description>
 <link>http://teste.html</link>
 <item>
  <title>Teste numero 5 - 31/10/2017</title>
  <description>
      Descrição teste
  </description>
  <link>
     http://teste.html
  </link>
 </item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

Classe Channel:

```
@Root(name="rss", strict=false)
public class Channel {

@Element(name = "title")
private String title;

@Element(name = "description")
private String description;

@Element(name = "link")
private String link;

private Item horoscopeDescription;

public String getTitle() {return title;}

public void setTitle(String title) {this.title = title;}

public String getDescription() { return description;}

public void setDescription(String description) { this.description= description;}

public Item getHoroscopeDescription(){ return this.horoscopeDescription;}

public void setLink(String title) { this.link = link;}

public String getLink(String title) { return link;}
```

Class Item:

@Root(name="item", strict=false)
public class Item {

```
@Element(name = "title")
private String title;

@Element(name = "description")
private String description;

public String getTitle() {return title;}

public void setTitle(String title) {this.title = title;}

public String getDescription() {return description;}

public void setDescription(String description) {this.description = description;}
```

}

Já li várias páginas sobre este tema, mas não consigo arranjar uma solução. Alguém pode ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você marcou o atributo `title` como `required` (essa é a configuração **default**). Em algum momento você está recebendo um XML **sem o elemento title**.

Tente marcar explicitamente `required` como `false`

```
@Element(name = "title",required = false)
private String title;
```